# Memory not freed when using storyboard segues + dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I tried to debug this memory issue with a more complex app for bit, but since the problem also occurs in a minimal test app, I guess that means that it's something about the basic structure that doesn't work as expected (or at least as we're expecting it).

Here's the setup:

[image]

So a Storyboard with three view controllers connected with segues. The buttons in the MainViewController trigger the segues, the "close" buttons in the ImageViewController dismiss them via `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. (Note that I'm just using large images as an example - what matters is that displaying those view controllers will occupy some non-trivial amount of memory).

Here's the code for all three:

**MainViewController:**

```
 class MainViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBAction func openFirstImage(sender: UIButton) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstImageSegue", sender: sender)
        }

        @IBAction func openSecondImage(sender: UIButton) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondImageSegue", sender: sender)
        }
    }
```

**FirstImageVC:**

```
class FirstImageVC: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func close(sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**SecondImageVC:**

```
class SecondImageVC: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func close(sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Running the app, these are the allocations for the following events - launching the app, opening the first picture, closing the first picture, opening the second picture, closing the second picture:

[image]

They seem to keep adding up and are never released.

Now, whenever I pop back to the MainViewController, I would like to have a "clean" memory again. So the question has two aspects:

- **Why doesn't this setup work this way** - who's keeping a reference to the view controller after it's dismissal?
- And **is there a way to "fix" this behaviour?** (Ideally without overhauling the entire navigational structure of the project).

Comment: Did you set a restoration ID in your view controllers? If so, the system will save a snapshot of whatever state it was in when the view controller was closed.l

Comment: @NRitH That's not it, I'm afraid. No restoration IDs set for any of the view controllers.